# Need to create a specific database in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I need to create a database with 3 fields - a unique identifier, 2 integer fields. The integers need to be taken as input from the user. The content of the database needs to be displayed when content is added. Also, it should be possible to delete content from the database. 
Please help me with this code

Answer (score 1):

Use SQLite database http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db There are thousands tutorials about it in the internet